# How to convert String to jsonObject in Java?

Tags: java

This is string from jsonObject

```
{"no":1000,"name":"xxx","code":345}
```

I want convert to this string to JSONObject.
Code here

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8090/search?numer="+no);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "+ conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
    String output ;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);//output:{"no":1000,"name":"xxx","code":345}
    }
    conn.disconnect();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific question here that you want to ask? Because pure code writing requests aren't on topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can check out Jackson and this tutorial: https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: @Jack Flamp: i asked string to object, not reverse

Comment: @Java Read the article. It's both ways.

Comment: @Jack Flamp: i'm getting nullpointer exception

Comment: @Java Did you create a POJO class that corresponds to the JSON? See answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 1: Add these two lines

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(output);
```

Step 2: Add below dependency to pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: ok tq now i am getting string, means **{"no":1000,"name":"xxx","code":345}**. Now how to convert **{"data":[{"no":1000,"name":"xxx","code":345}]}** like this.

Comment: In the same way create another JSONObject and pass your JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Jackson. Example here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Create a POJO. I don't know what the type is but since it has name as field `name` I will call it `User`.

```
public class User {
    private int no;
    private String name;
    private int code;

    //getters setters
}
```

Then something like this:

```
 User user = mapper.readValue(output, User.class);
```

Comment: same thing i did **Data staff1 = mapper.readValue(output, Data.class);
   System.out.println(staff1);**

Comment: Ok, add your Data class and update the test code and maybe I can see what you are missing. Though I can't test it from where I am right now. What is the nullpointer you get? `mapper` or `staff1`

Comment: ok tq now i am getting string, means {"no":1000,"name":"xxx","code":345}. Now how to convert {"data":[{"no":1000,"name":"xxx","code":345}]} like this.